# How to create a histogram of a distance table

Tags: r, histogram, igraph, network-analysis

I'm currently using the `igraph` package and conducting my first network analysis. I have an directed dataset as such:

```
m=matrix(nrow=3,ncol=3)
m[1,1]=0
m[1,2]=1
m[1,3]=1
m[2,1]=1
m[2,2]=0
m[2,3]=0
m[3,1]=0
m[3,2]=1
m[3,3]=0
```

I created the list 'objects.'

```
object <- graph.adjacency(m,mode="directed")
```

I have been working with the various `distances` functions and found the `distance_table` function. R Documents the function as:

> `distance_table` calculates a histogram, by calculating the shortest path length between each pair of vertices. For directed graphs both directions are considered, so every pair of vertices appears twice in the histogram.

I assigned the distance table to dt:

```
dt <- distance_table(object, directed = TRUE)
```

However, I cannot figure out how to plot the histogram. I have tried:

```
hist(dt)
hist(dt[1])
```

and

```
plot(dt)
```

However, none of them worked. How would I plot this histogram?

Comment: Maybe: `barplot(dt$res)` ?

Comment: Yep, that worked. I thought It would look different but thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*distance_table* returns a list, check the structure:

```
str(dt)
# List of 2
# $ res        : num [1:2] 4 2
# $ unconnected: num 0
```

Then plot the relevant data - `"res"`:

```
barplot(dt$res)
```

[image]